# Input phone number should be only integers in javascript, and give error if anything inserted in it except integers

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function validateForm()
        {
        var v = document.getElementById("id1").value;
        var x=v.toString().length;
         if (x!=""){
        alert("here");
        if(x>9 && (x>47 || x<58))
        {
        alert("Great");
        }
        else
        {
        alert("Enter Valid number");
        }}
        else{
        alert("Enter Number please");
        }}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form name="myForm"
        onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"
        Name: <input type="text" name="number" id="id1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="number" name="number" id="id1">
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only html then you can use

```
<input type="number" name="mn" id="id1">
```

via javascript you can do it also

```
function validateForm()
{
          var v = document.getElementById("id1").value;

         if (v){
          var testn = /^-?[0-9]+$/;
           if(testn.test(v)){

           }else{
             alert("Please Insert valid Number");
           }
         }else{
           alert("Please insert MN");
         }
}
```

Comment: , but i want to do it in JScript when i m doing it, it is accepting special character

Comment: can u explain me  "  if (v){
          var testn = /^-?[0-9]+$/;
           if(testn.test(v))" these lines plz

Comment: if(v) means if your input has a value   . var testn = /^-?[0-9]+$/; it is basically regular expression which validate your input should be a number..for more:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: No, i want to use my own logic, not a regular expression sir. Please tell me the own logic, not predefined.

Comment: this is your own logic brother..regular expression is very good things it will help you in all languages

Comment: I understand, but put the logic in my code, not regular expression because i m creating pluggins. I just want my own logic .

Comment: what your logic...do u want to check one by one from 1 to 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000..which i have created thats my own logic..if you are so much interested in your own logic then build your own language why you are using javascript function's, JS IF...ELSE etc.

Comment: Ty somuch, dont be rude, if u dont want to , its k.

Comment: sorry @shahzebkhan